# Dynamic controller for a single route using route params in AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, router

Basically we have a lot of controllers and templates and we wanted to dynamically load both the controller and the template for a given route.

Something along the lines of:

```
$routeProvider.when('/page/:page', {
  templateUrl: fuction(params) {
    return '/templates/pages/' + params.page;
  },

  controller: function(params) {
    return params.page + 'Controller';
  }
})
```

However we don't receive the `params` argument for the controller function. Is there any way to achieve this kind of flexibility?

Answer (score 0):

I guess you can use the `$injector.instantiate` function which will invoke the given function using `new` with the dependencies injected. Since a controller is used as a constructor you just need to wrap the controller function like this:

`controller: function () {
    return $injector.instantiate(function (params) { ... });
}`

This is just a guess, I don't guarantee it will work.